Square an image with text next to it, and pad to impact the next element
I've been trying to find out how to square a rectangle image and have text appear to the left of it. I want the next element to be below it and currently - I'm not there. Please help me fix this coding.


body {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
<div class="square">
  <div>
    <img src="https://bespokeattireco.com/cdn/shop/files/IMG-1944.jpg?v=1699514408" width="auto" height="135px">
  </div>
  <p>
    Adding bands to the wrists allow the sleeves to take a different shape. Please note, bands will be the same color as rest of the garment unless otherwise stated in the notes box below.
  </p>
</div>



The problem's I'm having it a cannot figure out how to square the image. I got the text to the right side, but it is also moving the next eliment to the right side of the image as well which I don't want.

It might help if you could [edit] your question to include a visual mockup of the result you want. It's also not clear if you want the text to the left or right of the image

you can use flexbox for it


    .container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: flex-start;
}

.left {
 display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
 align-items: flex-start;
}

.square-image {
  flex:1;
  min-width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-right: 20px; 
  }

.below {
   margin-top: 10px; 
  }
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<img src="https://bespokeattireco.com/cdn/shop/files/IMG-1944.jpg?v=1699514408" alt="Image" class="square-image">
<span>Adding bands to the wrists allow the sleeves to take a different shape. Please note, bands will be the same color as rest of the garment unless otherwise stated in the notes box below.</span>
</div>
<div class="below">
<p>Next element content here</p>
</div>
</div>




I don't think reducing the text length just so you get a square image is a solution that will work for OP

I updated the code
